# Android intent for battery level = 0%

Tags: android, android-intent, android-hardware

My question has two parts:

a) When the battery level in android device reaches 0%, is it programmatically(forcefully) made to shutdown at this moment?

b) If yes, then can anyone tell me the particular battery intent(for 0% case) which is broadcast that forces the device shutdown when device battery level = 0% ?

Comment: You realize 0% means 0%, right?  Like, there's no (none, nada, zip, 0%) power and your phone will not be running.  It's not "made to shutdown" it simply can't run without power.  Also, if you want to simulate 0% then you can use an emulator and send the battery level with adb shell commands.

Comment: @BillMote : Actually, I am developing a kiosk using android tablet.The charging for this is done not from the usual usb port but using physical cables(directly to the battery).Due to this the charge level shown using the battery api is incorrect.So the battery level shown may reduce to 0(even though there is actual charge in the battery),and shuts down the device.I was wondering if I could capture the battery intent at 0% and abort it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: http://blog.rabidgremlin.com/2010/11/05/android-tips-the-emulator/

Comment: @BillMote: That battery low intent is fired on my device when the battery reaches say at 15% 8% 4%.Will check for the 0% and also the technique using emulator as you suggested.

Comment: @BillMote: Can you pls have a look at this as well : " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369834/remove-android-system-app-files-that-monitors-the-battery-level "